# ASP.NET MVC: Null Foreign Key ID leads to Validation Errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

**Short Story:**

I load a model instance from db, apply changes to it but when I want to update the changes, Validation exceptions happens for foreign key items which set as `[Required]` in model definition. I've found a work around but I don't know what is the right way to fix this?

**Details:**

I have a model as below:

```
public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 5]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual ApplicationUser Client { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Client")]
    public string ClientID;


    [Required]
    public virtual ApplicationUser ProjectManager { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("ProjectManager")]
    public string ProjectManagerID;

    [Range(0,100)]
    [Required]
    public int Progress { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    [Column("Disabled")]
    public bool Disabled{ get; set; }

    [Column("Status")]
    public string Status{ get; set; }



}
```

Whenever I fetch model information from db into an instance an apply changes to it, I face exceptions which are about required `ProjectManager` and `Client`.

```
Project currentProject = (from prj in dbContext.Projects
                                      where prj.Id == project.Id).Single();
//---> currentProject.ProjectManagerID      is  null 
//---> currentProject.ClientID              is  null 
//---> currentProject.ProjectManager        is  present
//---> currentProject.Client                is  present

currentProject.Name = ....
currentProject.Progress = ....
currentProject.Status = ....
currentProject.Disabled = ....
dbContext.Entry(currentProject).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
dbContext.SaveChanges();        //--> Validation error for required Client,ProjectManager
```

This is caused by the fact that when I ftech information from DB, ClientID and ProjectManagerID are null and if I set them manually as below, it will fix:

```
            currentProject.Name = project.Name;
            currentProject.Progress = project.Progress;
            currentProject.Status = project.Status;
            currentProject.Disabled = project.Disabled;
            currentProject.ProjectManagerID = currentProject.ProjectManager.Id;
            currentProject.ClientID = currentProject.Client.Id;
            try
            {
                dbContext.Entry(currentProject).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                dbContext.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
            {
                addValidationErrorsToModelState(e);
                return View(project);
            }
```

I'm suspicious to `virtual` settings but not sure, because  foreign objects are loaded but their ID is null.

P.S. I declared projects in AppDbContext as below:

```
    public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I missed setter/getter for ID properties of ForeignKeys:

```
public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 5]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual ApplicationUser Client { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("Client")]
    public string ClientID{ get; set; } //<--fixed 


    [Required]
    public virtual ApplicationUser ProjectManager { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("ProjectManager")]
    public string ProjectManagerID { get; set; } //<--fixed 

    [Range(0,100)]
    [Required]
    public int Progress { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    [Column("Disabled")]
    public bool Disabled{ get; set; }

    [Column("Status")]
    public string Status{ get; set; }

}
```